# why DKIM bad signature

Tags: filter, email, postfix-mta, dkim

I have setup a postfix mail receiving server.

On this I am using DKIM milter to verify incoming mail DKIM signatures.

From some email clients I am getting the following 'bad signature data' error:

```
Jun  7 02:10:09 ip-10-194-99-63 dkim-filter[27964]: (unknown-jobid) no signing domain match for `gmail.com'
Jun  7 02:10:09 ip-10-194-99-63 dkim-filter[27964]: (unknown-jobid) no signing subdomain match for `gmail.com'
Jun  7 02:10:09 ip-10-194-99-63 dkim-filter[27964]: (unknown-jobid) no signing keylist match for `sudipta.test@gmail.com'
Jun  7 02:10:09 ip-10-194-99-63 dkim-filter[27964]: (unknown-jobid) not internal
Jun  7 02:10:09 ip-10-194-99-63 dkim-filter[27964]: (unknown-jobid) not authenticated
Jun  7 02:10:09 ip-10-194-99-63 dkim-filter[27964]: (unknown-jobid) mode select: verifying
Jun  7 02:10:09 ip-10-194-99-63 dkim-filter[27964]: BA6E210015D: bad signature data
Jun  7 02:10:10 ip-10-194-99-63 postfix/cleanup[30131]: BA6E210015D: milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from mail-pv0-f176.google.com[74.125.83.176]: 5.7.0 bad DKIM signature data; from=<sudipta.test@gmail.com> to=<qwe@dev1.cpgtest.ostinet.net> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-pv0-f176.google.com>
```

can anybody give me any clue why I am getting the above error in my postfix logs

and

what remedies I can put in to rectify or workaround this

or

warn the sender.

Thanks in advance

Ashish Sharma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem faced after i started using [OpenDKIM](http://www.opendkim.org/) instead of dkim-filter.

OpenDKIM is forked from dkim-filter code only.