# OpenDKIM or dkim-milter

Tags: postfix-mta, dkim

I need to add DKIM to a Postfix installation.  I've found two implementations that work with Postfix. [OpenDKIM](http://www.opendkim.org/), and dkim-milter [dkim-milter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dkim-milter/). The former claims to be a fork of the latter.

OpenDKIM appears to be the more active project, judging from releases and mailing list activity.

Which of these implementations (or another) should I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least  [one other user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987486/why-dkim-bad-signature) found that OpenDKIM worked better.  So I would probably try that first.